# How to combine multiple Ansible filters?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How do I combine the Ansible filters, `json_query` and `basename` so that I can do it in one task instead of using two tasks as shown here?

```yaml
- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    filename: "{{ file1 | json_query('files[*].path') }}"

- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    filename: "{{ filename | basename }}"
```

I tried these ways, but both resulted in the same type of error:

```yaml
- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    filename: "{{ file1 | json_query('files[*].path') | basename }}"
```

```
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ file1 | json_query('files[*].path') | basename }}): expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"
```

```yaml
- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    filename: "{{ (file1 | json_query('files[*].path')) | basename }}"
```

```
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (file1 | json_query('files[*].path')) | basename }}): expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"
}
```

Comment: According the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data) you've used already the correct approach. Therefore and since I am not able to reproduce an "didn't work", can you provide the variable content of each task and related debug output?

Comment: Please take note that [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) will work on one path only and not on a list of paths (`files[*].path`).

Answer (score 3):

Given the variable *file1* for testing

```yaml
  file1:
    files:
      - path: /tmp/example/test_1.conf
      - path: /tmp/example/test_2.conf
      - path: /tmp/example/test_3.conf
```

your query

```yaml
  filename: "{{ file1|json_query('files[].path') }}"
```

gives the list of the paths

```yaml
  filename:
  - /tmp/example/test_1.conf
  - /tmp/example/test_2.conf
  - /tmp/example/test_3.conf
```

If you want the files' names only *map* the filter *basename* in the pipe

```yaml
  result: "{{ file1|json_query('files[].path')|map('basename') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  result:
  - test_1.conf
  - test_2.conf
  - test_3.conf
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    file1:
      files:
        - path: /tmp/example/test_1.conf
        - path: /tmp/example/test_2.conf
        - path: /tmp/example/test_3.conf

    filename: "{{ file1|json_query('files[].path') }}"
    result: "{{ file1|json_query('files[].path')|map('basename') }}"
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: filename
    - debug:
        var: result
```

Comment: Good example for [Loops and list comprehensions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) with `map` "_a basic for loop that just allows you to change every item in a list, using the `attribute` keyword you can do the transformation based on attributes of the list elements_", therefore +1